# Transaction aborted when accessing versioned row in table 'dbo.sysmail_profile' in database 'msdb'

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, database-mail, msdb, tempdb-version-store

I'm having some problens with SQL Database mail, basicaly anything that I try to do gives me an error like this one below:

> Transaction aborted when accessing versioned row in table 'dbo.sysmail_profile' in database 'msdb'. Requested versioned row was not found. Your tempdb is probably out of space. Please refer to BOL on how to configure tempdb for versioning.

The error is when I try to delete a profile from database mail, but if I run a query related to change/create a profile, it gives me an error similar to this one.

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_delete_profile_sp
@profile_name = 'Notification';
```

My tempdb is not full and there is lot of space in the tempdb and in the disk, I also tried to restart the database, but it did not work.

Any ideas about what this error can be? I'm kinda stuck with this problem and could not find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried `DBCC CHECKDB ('msdb') WITH NO_INFOMSGS`

Comment: Yes, it returns "Commands completed successfully."